React Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node'
Whenever I'm above the Tab size (768px) isTab=true so the cards get rendered normally. But when I go below 768px isTab=false and then the TinySlider carousel gets playing also as expected. The real problem starts when I resize my screen again above 768px isTab=true It gives off this error of failed to execute the removeChild Don't know what's the real issue here, as the Tiny Slider automatically adds some divs and classes of it's own to make the carousel :(
const RenderCards: React.FC<ParentComponentProps> = ({ isTab }) => {
  const cards = (
    <>
      <div>
        ---- Some cards content ----
      </div>
      <div>
        ---- Some cards content ----
      </div>
      <div>
        ---- Some cards content ----
      </div>
    </>
  );

  return (<>
  {isTab && (
    <div className="flex" key="services-cards">
      {cards}
    </div>
  )}
  <div key="somerandomshit">

{!isTab && (

    <TinySlider
      key="services-cards"
      settings={{
        lazyload: true,
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 1.1,
          },
          768: {
            items: 3,
          },
          992: {
            items: 3,
          },
          1200: {
            items: 3,
          },
        },
        speed: 1000,
        nav: true,
        mouseDrag: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 2000,
        controls: false,
        autoplayButtonOutput: false,
        disable: isTab ? true : false,
      }}
    >
      {cards}
    </TinySlider>
)
}
</div>
</>);
};


Trying to put responsive cards as in whenever it's below tab size it should play as a Carousel and whenever it's above Tab size it should render as normal cards with flex side by side
